# Why does 2 compare greater than 2,5?

Tags: c, int, compare, double

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1;

    if (++x > 2,5)
        printf("%d", ++x);
    else
        printf("%d", x++);
}
```

I don't understand why the output is `3`. `++x == 2` and `2 > 2,5` is false. But the compiler says the `if` statement evaluates to true.  What is the reason?

Comment: Because `5` is `true`, which is evaluated after `++x > 2`

Comment: `2,5` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Use dot `.` for the decimal point in C source code.  Use comma `,` to separate arguments to functions, or as the comma operator but beware — the comma operator causes confusion very easily.  You're using it as a comma operator, whether you know it or not.  (And a consequence of using a comma operator is that `2 > 2,5` evaluates as if you'd written `++x; if (5) …` and `5` is true, not false as you said in the question.)

Comment: @P__J__ — I didn't immediately find a question that covers the correct syntax for a `double` constant.  The best I can suggest is the C standard itself: C11 [§6.4.4.2 Floating constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.2).  There is no provision there for the use of comma as the decimal point.  I/O can use locales ([`setlocale()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html) and 
[`localeconv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localeconv.html)) to use comma as the decimal point.

Comment: @P__J__ I used that duplicate because it seems to answer the *actual* question: "What is the reason [the `if` statement evaluates to `true`]?"

Comment: @thinkblue Should be `2.5`. The creators of C weren't thinking about other countries, huh?

Comment: I'm not sure why the entire conversation is about `,` and `.` . I'm sure that @thinkblue has not made a mistake here by using 2,5 instead of 2.5. His question is why as per below code if statement evaluates to true 
`if ( 2 > 2,5 ) 
printf("Yes 2 is greater"); 
else 
printf("No 2 is not greater");`

Answer (score 0):

`2,5` is not the correct syntax for a `double` constant. `2.5` is. Which is probably unfortunate for people living in countries where `,` is the decimal point.

Comment: I'm sure that @thinkblue has not made a mistake here by using 2,5 instead of 2.5. His question is why as per below code if statement evaluates to true

`if ( 2 > 2,5 )
        printf("Yes 2 is greater");
    else
        printf("No 2 is not greater");`